# excel 2007 updating new adjacent cell value when reference cell i s updated

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007

I have to copy or update cell value to new adjacent cell every time when reference cell value is updated.

I have Cell `A1` with some formula, which updates it value frequently. what i need to do is, every time when value of `A1` gets updated, that value should be copied in new adjacent cell.

if `A1` is `20`, then `B1` should be `20`.

Again if `A1` id updated to new value `23`, then `B1` should be `20` but C1 should be `23`,so on.

```
update 1: A1=20  B1=20
update 2: A1=23  B1=20   C1=23
update 3: A1=25  B1=20   C1=23  D1=25
```

Answer (score 0):

This small *Event macro* will place the latest **A1** value at the end of the first row:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
    Dim v As Variant, N As Long

    v = Range("A1").Value
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    If Range("B1").Value = "" Then
        Range("B1").Value = v
        Application.EnableEvents = True
        Exit Sub
    End If

    N = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    If Cells(1, N).Value = v Then
        Application.EnableEvents = True
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Cells(1, N + 1).Value = v
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Because it is worksheet code, it is very easy to install and automatic to use:

1. right-click the tab name near the bottom of the Excel window
2. select View Code - this brings up a VBE window
3. paste the stuff in and close the VBE window

If you have any concerns, first try it on a trial worksheet.

If you save the workbook, the macro will be saved with it.
If you are using a version of Excel later then 2003, you must save
the file as **.xlsm** rather than **.xlsx**

To remove the macro:

1. bring up the VBE windows as above
2. clear the code out
3. close the VBE window

To learn more about macros in general, see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/getstarted.htm

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735(v=office.14).aspx

To learn more about Event Macros (worksheet code), see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/event.htm

**Macros must be enabled for this to work!**

Comment: Gary thanks earlier but would you mind telling every steps detailed as i am new to macro or VBA